# Uneven line spacing in Beamer title page

Tags: beamer, line-spacing, beamer-metropolis

I have a custom title page for a Beamer presentation using the metropolis theme. Trying to set up two columns results in uneven line spacing in the right column.

[image: Unneven line spacing]

Here's the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=43,9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[numbering=fraction,titleformat section=allsmallcaps]{metropolis}

\setlength{\leftmargini}{2ex}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

\newcommand{\detail}[1]{%
  {\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute}#1}
}

\title[April 2020]{Terraform}
\subtitle{Module Architecture Proposition}
\date{Thursday, June 11th}
\author{Joey Dumont}
\institute[\textsc{Group}]{Group\\%
Branch\\%
Org%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering,fragile]
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \insertauthor\par
    \vspace{-0.25em}{\scriptsize\detail{\texttt{<joey.dumont@org.ca>}}}\\
    \vspace{1em}
    \usebeamertemplate*{date}

    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \usebeamertemplate*{institute}
  \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any idea why this happens, and how I can fix it?

Comment: In `beamer`, `\insertauthor` defines and sets `\institute`, so that uses the (large) baseline of the author.  However, since the baseline isn't "frozen" until the end of a paragraph, or at an explicit line end (`\\ `), and the last line of the `\institute` argument is explicitly *not* ended with a paragraph break, the baseline for that line reverts to the default, which is much less than that for the author.    So, either add `\par` at the end of the last institution line, or reset the baselines for the institution block.

Comment: I tried adding `\par` to the end of institute, like this: ```\institute[\textsc{InfraOps}]{Group\\%
Branch\\%
Org\par
}
```, but got the same result. I'll try to see what the `baselineskip` to reset to in that case.

Comment: You tightened up the line with the email address.  You can do the same thing between the first and second lines of the `\institute` with `\\[<dimen>]`.  (Actually, `em` is really meant for horizontal dimensions; `ex` is the corresponding vertical unit.)

Comment: I did that for the email address because I was manually aligning different elements. I would prefer having a way to fix the `institute` fix without manually changing the line spacing between each line. Also, using `\\[1ex]` [didn't fix it](https://imgur.com/c34rQSP). Is there a more idiomatic way of using these Beamer commands such that the formatting for `institute` is correct? (Thanks for the tip about `ex` and `em`, I always get those mixed up).

Comment: Ok, I've been away from LaTeX a while, so I forgot how `\author` and `\institute` behave, especially with regards to multi-line content. My aim with `\usebeamertemplate*{institute}` was to use the default `institute` style in Metropolis, but given that I'm not using the typical `\institute` behaviour as regards to placement, it's probably easier to just do `{\scriptsize\detail{Group\\Branch\\Org\par}}`, where `\detail` is defined in the question.

Comment: That's a good solution.  I've never used `\institution`, although I've used `beamer`. (I usually just "roll my own".)  I was just looking at the code to see how things are defined.  Glad you've got a result that you're happy with.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.